# Approximation of function that has Lipschitz-continuous $n$-th derivative

Tags: approximation-theory, smoothness

Good afternoon. I'm trying to find in literature the solution for such a problem: for given function with $L_p$-Lipschitz continuous $p$-th derivative I need to find function $f_\varepsilon$ with $L_n$-Lipschitz continuous $n$-th derivative for $n > p$ such that $|f - f_\varepsilon| < \varepsilon$ on compact set of radius $R$. Additionally, I need some "precision" depending on $p, n$ to be known, i.e. $\varepsilon \sim \varepsilon(p, n)$. I want to start from something simple, at least from $p=1, n=2$ (for $p=0, n=1$ I can easily use dual smoothing, so it's not interesting), but couldn't find anything. Ideally, I hope that there is some result for arbitrary $p > 0$ and $n = p+1$. Please, advice me some articles.